# What is the best approach for calling same API from multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have more than 20 view controllers in an app. Now I'm calling a particular api from 2 different view controllers to get data from server. What is the best approach to reduce the code repetition?

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
class Api {

  static func getData(completion:@escaping:([Model]) -> ()) { // suppose you receive an array 
     // api call here {
        comletion(data)
     }
 }
```

Then call it like this inside any vc

```
Api.getData { (data) in
   print(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **`singleton`** to support all your `API calls` like:

```
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    private init() {}

    func fetchData(with urlString: String, handler: ((Model?, Error?)->())?)  {
        //Add other params as per your requirement...
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                //parse your data here...
                handler?(model, error) //model is the object you got after parsing the data..
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

In your `ViewController`, you can use it like:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    func fetchData() {
        APIManager.shared.fetchData(with: "YOUR_URL_STRING") { (model, error) in
            //Use model here...
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I've taken the example of `URLSession` for API call. You can use other ways like 3rd parties (`Alamofire` etc.) as per your requirement.